# I was trying to execute test case from spring-kafka-cloud-binder-streams github repository. My test case is failing with following error

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder

I am replicating exact code from this github
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/main/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/streams/integration/KafkastreamsBinderPojoInputStringOutputIntegrationTests.java

@GaryRussell
@SobyChako

```
package com.lululemon.retail.aurus.storeclosestream.streamtest;/*
 * Copyright 2017-2018 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */


import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.Field;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Grouped;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TimeWindows;


import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.WebApplicationType;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.integration.test.util.TestUtils;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.StreamsBuilderFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.CleanupConfig;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerde;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.rule.EmbeddedKafkaRule;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.utils.KafkaTestUtils;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

/**
 * @author Marius Bogoevici
 * @author Soby Chacko
 * @author Gary Russell
 *
 *
 */
public class KafkastreamsBinderPojoInputStringOutputIntegrationTests {

    public static HashMap<String,String> brokerProp(){
        HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<>();
        hmap.put("listeners","PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092");
        hmap.put("port","9092");
        hmap.put("socket.request.max.bytes","409296129");

        return hmap;
    }


    @ClassRule
    public static EmbeddedKafkaRule embeddedKafkaRule = new EmbeddedKafkaRule(1, true,
            "counts-id");
//.brokerProperties(KafkastreamsBinderPojoInputStringOutputIntegrationTests.brokerProp()) //TODO: this is not working
    private static EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka = embeddedKafkaRule
            .getEmbeddedKafka();
    private static Consumer<String, String> consumer;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> consumerProps = KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps("group-id",
                "false", embeddedKafka);
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String> cf = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
                consumerProps);
        consumer = cf.createConsumer();
        embeddedKafka.consumeFromAnEmbeddedTopic(consumer, "counts-id");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {
        consumer.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void testKstreamBinderWithPojoInputAndStringOuput() throws Exception {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(ProductCountApplication.class);
        app.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE);
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = app.run("--server.port=0",
                "--spring.jmx.enabled=false",
                "--spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.process-in-0=input",
                "--spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.process-out-0=output",
                "--spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=foos",
                "--spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=counts-id",
                "--spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.commit.interval.ms=1000",
                "--spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.key.serde"
                        + "=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde",
                "--spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.value.serde"
                        + "=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde",
                "--spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.input.consumer.applicationId=ProductCountApplication-xyz",
                "--spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.brokers="
                        + embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString());
        try {
            receiveAndValidateFoo();
            // Assertions on StreamBuilderFactoryBean
            StreamsBuilderFactoryBean streamsBuilderFactoryBean = context
                    .getBean("&stream-builder-process", StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.class);
            CleanupConfig cleanup = TestUtils.getPropertyValue(streamsBuilderFactoryBean,
                    "cleanupConfig", CleanupConfig.class);
            assertThat(cleanup.cleanupOnStart()).isFalse();
            assertThat(cleanup.cleanupOnStop()).isFalse();
        }
        finally {
            context.close();
        }
    }

    private void receiveAndValidateFoo() {
        Map<String, Object> senderProps = KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(embeddedKafka);
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<Integer, String> pf = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(
                senderProps);
        KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> template = new KafkaTemplate<>(pf, true);
        template.setDefaultTopic("foos");
        template.sendDefault(1,"{\"id\":\"123\"}");
        ConsumerRecord<String, String> cr = KafkaTestUtils.getSingleRecord(consumer,
                "counts-id");
        assertThat(cr.value().contains("Count for product with ID 123: 1")).isTrue();
    }

    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public static class ProductCountApplication {

        @Bean
        public Function<KStream<Object, Product>, KStream<Integer, String>> process() {
            return input -> input.filter((key, product) -> product.getId() == 123)
                    .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(value, value))
                    .groupByKey(Grouped.with(new JsonSerde<>(Product.class),
                            new JsonSerde<>(Product.class)))
                    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMillis(5000)))
                    .count(Materialized.as("id-count-store")).toStream()
                    .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(key.key().id,
                            "Count for product with ID 123: " + value));
        }

    }

    static class Product {

        Integer id;

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

    }

}
```

When I try to execute this, I get following error

```
java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:483) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:472) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:694) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.doConnect(Selector.java:277) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:255) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:990) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.access$600(NetworkClient.java:73) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:1161) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:1049) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:558) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:265) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1297) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1238) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1211) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:980) ~[kafka-streams-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollPhase(StreamThread.java:933) ~[kafka-streams-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:751) ~[kafka-streams-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:604) ~[kafka-streams-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:576) ~[kafka-streams-3.1.2.jar:na]
```

```
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic foos not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:666)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:409)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.sendDefault(KafkaTemplate.java:387)
    at com.lululemon.retail.aurus.storeclosestream.streamtest.KafkastreamsBinderPojoInputStringOutputIntegrationTests.receiveAndValidateFoo(KafkastreamsBinderPojoInputStringOutputIntegrationTests.java:137)
    at com.lululemon.retail.aurus.storeclosestream.streamtest.KafkastreamsBinderPojoInputStringOutputIntegrationTests.testKstreamBinderWithPojoInputAndStringOuput(KafkastreamsBinderPojoInputStringOutputIntegrationTests.java:117)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic foos not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```